# Get difference in task count from opened and closed date for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to make a waterfall chart (in a reporting app) that shows the additions and resolutions of tasks based on their Opened At and Resolved At timestamps

I have a database on MSSQL Server 2016 that contains a "task" table:

```
SELECT [SysID], [Opened At], [Resolved At]
FROM task
ORDER BY [Opened At] ASC;

SysID                               Opened At               Resolved At
9086c6254f3d578070a1afee0310c79a    2018-04-30 23:53:25.000 2018-05-01 00:57:46.000
7c86c6254f3d578070a1afee0310c7c8    2018-04-30 23:53:27.000 2018-05-01 01:05:22.000
9d8606254f3d578070a1afee0310c7a9    2018-04-30 23:53:29.000 2018-05-01 01:05:42.000
f986c6254f3d578070a1afee0310c783    2018-04-30 23:53:31.000 2018-05-01 01:14:22.000
45c312e94ffd5780a35d87501310c775    2018-05-01 00:51:22.000 2018-05-01 04:11:48.000
```

A task is considered "active" if it has an "Opened At" timestamp without a "Resolved At" timestamp. Tasks are not always marked resolved within the day they are opened, so I want to see how many get left over at the end of each day.

I would like to end up with this SQL result, that shows the difference in active tickets at the end of each day:

```
Date Created    Opened Count    Closed Count    Difference
27/10/2017      17              5               12
28/10/2017      11              13              -2
29/10/2017      10              9               1
30/10/2017      17              12              5
31/10/2017      17              20              -3
1/11/2017       23              19              4
2/11/2017       19              25              -6
3/11/2017       13              30              -17
```

My current query is

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), task.[Opened At], 126) AS [Date Opened],
      SUM(CASE WHEN [Opened At] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Opened Count]
      FROM task GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), task.[Opened At], 126) 

      UNION ALL
      SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), task.[Resolved At], 126) AS [Date Resolved],
      SUM(CASE WHEN [Resolved At] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Resolved Count]
      FROM task GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), task.[Resolved At], 126)
) t
```

However, it only ever returns the Date Opened and Opened Count columns. The Opened Count column has incorrect data in it. The query works fine if I just do the single select of Opened At or Closed At without the UNION. The difference should just be Closed Count - Opened Count.

Since a ticket needs to be open before it can be resolved, I want to base the date off the Opened At column.

I've had a look at a number of posts describing the subquery technique used above, but I can't work out why it's not returning the other column. I've explored COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY... ) but it all the examples I've seen are for tables where there are distinct events per row. (bank account with debits and credits is a common one, which doesn't match this structure which is more an update to the row to change what the query is counting).

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: why dont u just try without case statement, `count(*) and group by`

Comment: if a task `Open` and `Close` on different date, you want the `Close Count` to report based on which date ? `Open` or `Close` date ?

Comment: `Union all` expects equal number of expressions in both select statements, does this even execute ?

Comment: @Ven, yes. it will execute. But will get only 2 column : Date & count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just need to `group by` date. A simple modification in your script will do the trick

```
SELECT [Date Created]
    ,sum([Opened Count]) [Opened Count]
    ,sum([Resolved Count]) [Resolved Count]
    ,sum([Resolved Count]) - sum([Opened Count]) DifferenceCount
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), task.[Opened At], 126) AS [Date Created]
        ,count(*) AS [Opened Count]
        ,0 [Resolved Count]
    FROM task
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), task.[Opened At], 126)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), task.[Resolved At], 126) AS [Date Created]
        ,0 [Opened Count]
        ,count(*) AS [Opened Count] AS [Resolved Count]
    FROM task
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), task.[Resolved At], 126)
    ) t
GROUP BY [Date Created]
```

Comment: Thank you - that's worked. I was able to add additional columns in the top-level select and then group by to get further segmentation. I've generated the waterfall chart from the result and it looks perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking at isolated days:

- how many tasks got opened that day
- how many tasks got resolved that day

You are not intersted in how many tasks are actually open at the end of a day (for which we'd have to add up all unresolved tasks opened that day or before).

So it's merely a full outer join of opened tasks per day with resolved tasks per day:

```
select
  coalesce(opened.dt, closed.dt) as day,
  coalesce(opened.cnt, 0) as opened_count,
  coalesce(resolved.cnt, 0) as resolved_count,
  coalesce(opened.cnt, 0) - coalesce(resolved.cnt, 0) as diff
from
(
  select convert(date, [Opened At]) as dt, count(*) as cnt
  from task
  group by convert(date, [Opened At])
) opened
full outer join
(
  select convert(date, [Resolved At]) as dt, count(*) as cnt
  from task
  group by convert(date, [Resolved At])
) resolved on resolved.dt = opened.dt
order by day;
```

Comment: Thank you for this SQL. It appears to do the trick, but I had trouble with adding additional columns to the select from task. I've learned a bit about coalesce though - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a full join between the opened and resolved.

But with an additional twist.
Add a Total for those that were opened and resolved on the same day.

Because, if you really want to know how many were resolved on the same day as they were opened? 
Then just comparing the opened and closed totals would be misleading.

For example if you have only the tupples ([Opened At],[Resolved At]):
('2018-01-01','2018-01-02'), ('2018-01-02','2018-01-01')

Then on both 'Created At' days the TotalOpened = 1 and TotalClosed = 1, and Diff = 0
Since Diff = 0, one could assume that there were none that got resolved on another day.
But in reality, neither of the 2 tupples were opened and closed on the same day.

**Example Snippet:**

```
declare @task table (id int identity(1,1), [Opened At] datetime, [Resolved At] datetime);

insert into @task ([Opened At], [Resolved At]) values
 (GetDate()-1.1, GetDate()-1)
,(GetDate()-2, GetDate()-1)
,(GetDate()-3, GetDate()-2)
,(GetDate()-5, GetDate()-4)
;

select 
coalesce([OpenedDate],[ClosedDate]) as [Created At], 
isnull(TotalOpened,0) as [Opened Count], 
isnull(TotalClosed,0) as [Closed Count],
isnull(TotalOpened,0) - isnull(TotalClosed,0) as [Difference],
isnull(TotalSameDayClosure,0) as [SameDayClosure Count] 
from 
(
    select 
     convert(date,[Opened At]) as [OpenedDate], 
     count(*) as TotalOpened,
     count(case when [Resolved At] is not null and convert(date,[Opened At]) = convert(date,[Resolved At]) then 1 end) as TotalSameDayClosure
    from @task
    group by convert(date,[Opened At])
) Opened
full join
(
    select convert(date,[Resolved At]) as [ClosedDate], count(*) as TotalClosed
    from @task
    group by convert(date,[Resolved At])
) Closed
on Opened.[OpenedDate] = Closed.[ClosedDate];
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The query is used to figure out what our task "balance" is - are we closing more than are opened or vice-versa. A balance of 0 in this case is understood to mean "we were on top of our work for that day".

Comment: @Hellfire Ok. Oh well, guess you learned another trick then in case you'd need it later.